# How to make multiple rectangles not using hard-coding in google maps api?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

```
let map, infoWindow;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 37.460074, lng: 126.952568 },
    zoom: 16,
  }
);


    const rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map,
        bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(20.39623, 77.85009),
            new google.maps.LatLng(24.39623, 80.85009)
            )
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    const locationButton = document.createElement("button");

    locationButton.textContent = "Pan to Current Location";
    locationButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(locationButton);
    locationButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            const pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent("Location found.");
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
        },
        () => {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
        );
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
    });
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(
    browserHasGeolocation
        ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed."
        : "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation."
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

I already know to make one rectangle in google maps api, but I don't know how to make multiple rectangles with using loops. I don't want to make all rectangles with using hard-coding like rectangle1, rectangle2. I expect that I have to change variable named bounds, but I don't know how to do it. How can I use loops to make many rectangles?

Comment: Where are the `many rectangles` to be located? Random lat/lng, next to one another or all in same place?

Comment: You need an array of `bounds`, then you can use them to make an array of `rectangles`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius next to one another!

Comment: @Nick How can I make an array of bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific requirements / objectives are a little vague  but based upon the comment that they (multiple rectangles) are to be `next to one another!` then some simple arithmetic using the LatLngBounds for the initial rectangle can be done to determine either the difference in east/west ( to effectively get the width of the rectangle ) or the north/south ( to effectively get the height of the rectangle )

With those differences you can easily plot the new lat/lng values and this draw a new rectangle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: </title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
            .gm-bttn{
                padding:1rem;
                color:gold;
                margin:0.25rem;
                border-radius:1rem;
                border:none;
                background:purple;
                transition:ease-in-out all 500ms;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .gm-bttn:hover{
                background:gold;
                color:purple
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                let shapes=[];
                let map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: { lat: 37.460074, lng: 126.952568 },
                    zoom: 16,
                });
                
                // your original rectangle bounds
                let bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(20.39623, 77.85009),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(24.39623, 80.85009)
                );
                
                // for convenience, convert bounds to json
                let json=bounds.toJSON();
                let delta={
                    long:Math.abs( json.west - json.east ),
                    lat:Math.abs( json.north - json.south )
                };
                
                // create your original rectangle.
                shapes.push(
                    new google.maps.Rectangle({
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: "#FF0000",
                        fillOpacity: 0.1,
                        map,
                        geodesic:true,
                        bounds:bounds
                    })
                );
                
                // A ring around the globe of rectangles...
                let max=360 / Math.abs( delta.long );
                
                for( let i=1; i < max; i++ ){
                    // modify json based upon delta values for lat/lng
                    json.east -= delta.long,
                    json.west -= delta.long;
                    
                    // and then add a new rectangle
                    shapes.push(
                        new google.maps.Rectangle({
                            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            fillColor: "#FF0000",
                            fillOpacity: 0.1,
                            map,
                            geodesic:true,
                            bounds:json
                        })
                    );
                }
                

                let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                
                let clear=document.createElement('button');
                    clear.textContent='Remove rectangles'
                    clear.className='gm-bttn';
                    clear.addEventListener('click',( e )=>shapes.forEach( n=>n.setMap( null ) ) );

                let bttn = document.createElement('button');
                    bttn.textContent='Pan to Current Location';
                    bttn.className='gm-bttn';
                    
                    bttn.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
                        const errorhandler=()=>{
                            infoWindow.setPosition( map.getCenter() );
                            infoWindow.setContent( navigator.geolocation ? 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' : 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.' );
                            infoWindow.open( map );
                            return false;
                        };
                        const successhandler=( position )=>{
                            const pos = {
                                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                lng: position.coords.longitude,
                            };
                            infoWindow.setPosition( pos );
                            infoWindow.setContent( "Location found." );
                            infoWindow.open( map );
                            map.setCenter( pos );
                            return true;
                        };
                        const config={
                            enableHighAccuracy:true,
                            timeout:Infinity,
                            maximumAge:60000
                        };
                        if( navigator.geolocation ) {
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( successhandler, errorhandler, config );
                            return true;
                        }
                        return errorhandler();
                    });
                
                map.controls[ google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER ].push( bttn );
                map.controls[ google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER ].push( clear );
                map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
                map.fitBounds( bounds );
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Check out the [Proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/xodLutqr/1/) to see it in operation.

[image: for example...]

The same could be done for Latitude values if you wish - or both to completely cover the globe.