# Google Autocomplete api and map API throwing error in console and not loading API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

Im trying to get my  Google map API to work, i have an auto complete callback and a map callback but when i try to launch through chrome it throws this error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Its showing the API callback function as the error but i cant figure out why im pretty sure the callback is correct.

```js
<script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<mykey>=initMap&libraries=places'></script>
```

Comment: it seems that you do not have a event listener for your input field. The method "init" is only triggered once on page load. You need to call that function on every keypress event.

Comment: How would i go about fixing this? Thanks for your response.

Comment: *it wont autocomplete, it will not search, it will not work* - please provide debugging details. "It doesn't work" is not a proper problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include the maps api script twice - a single call that features both the libraries you wish to load and the other parameters will suffice.

In a similar vein - rather than a callback in the script uri and a separate `init` function call the `initMap` from the uri as per normal and invoke the `autocomplete` in the same context as the main map invocation. By doing this the scope is the same so both elements can live and work in harmony.

Much of the original code [seemed familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73597619/how-to-make-multiple-rectangles-not-using-hard-coding-in-google-maps-api/73598389#73598389) so I adapted what I wrote there slightly

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: </title>
        <style>
            body{
                width:100%;
                height:100vh;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:column;
            }
            #map{
                margin:auto;
                flex:20;
                width:100%;
                min-height:600px;
            }
            form{
                margin:auto;
                display:block;
                flex:1;
                padding:0.25rem 0;
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                align-items:center;
            }
            form label{ flex:1;background:grey;color:white;padding:0 0 0 1rem}
            form label input{padding:0.5rem}
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: {
                        lat: -34.397,
                        lng: 150.644
                    },
                    zoom: 6,
                });
                let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                let autocomplete=new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( document.forms.search.location );


                // make a button
                let bttn = document.createElement("button");
                    bttn.textContent = "Pan to Current Location";
                    bttn.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");


                // event handler for geolocation callback
                const clickhandler=()=>{
                    const errorhandler=()=>{
                        infoWindow.setPosition( map.getCenter() );
                        infoWindow.setContent( navigator.geolocation ? 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' : 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.' );
                        infoWindow.open( map );
                        return false;
                    };
                    const successhandler=( position )=>{
                        const pos = {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude,
                        };
                        infoWindow.setPosition( pos );
                        infoWindow.setContent( "Location found." );
                        infoWindow.open( map );
                        map.setCenter( pos );
                        return true;
                    };
                    const config={
                        enableHighAccuracy:true,
                        timeout:Infinity,
                        maximumAge:60000
                    };

                    if( navigator.geolocation ) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( successhandler, errorhandler, config );
                        return true;
                    }
                    return errorhandler();
                };
                
                
                const changehandler=(e)=>{
                    infoWindow.close();
                    
                    let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map
                    });
                    
                    map.setCenter( place.geometry.location );
                    map.setZoom( 14 );
                    
                    marker.setPosition( place.geometry.location );
                    marker.setVisible( true );
                    
                    infoWindow.open( map, marker );
                    infoWindow.setContent([ place.name, place.formatted_address ].join('<br />'));
                }
                
                
                // assign event handlers and add the button
                bttn.addEventListener( 'click', clickhandler );
                autocomplete.addListener( 'place_changed', changehandler );
                map.controls[ google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER ].push( bttn );
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap&libraries=places'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='search'>
            <label>Location: <input name='location' type='text' size='50' /></label>
        </form>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much for your answer!! iv done this but now its throwing an error at me Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND js:1. saying it cant find the javascript even though i have added the script source.

Comment: can you screenshot the error and add that?

Comment: I cant add pictures yet unfortunately my rep level isn't 10, this is exactly what displays in my console.Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl/js/page/js/page/index.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: No idea what that error refers to but it is not the code I posted which ran without error. Why is that referencing a `chrome-extension`?? What is that nonsense string??

Comment: im not to sure i think the main issue is the javascript not being found, ill try and work through it again, thanks so much for your help mate, i really appreciate it.

Comment: What you could do would be to [create a new paste](https://pastebin.com/) of the code as it is and share the link

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zf2dHQFh   i have added it here thanks mate.

Comment: Is that the code as you are running it?

Comment: Yes that exactly how I have it in VCS, but in 3 seperate docs and linking the CSS and JavaScript to the html file

Comment: I have even tried to straight copy the whole code into a Html file and run it that way, and it still wont load the javascript.